# parallels plesk file permission

Tags: webserver, plesk, parallels

I,m trying to install a joomla site in parallels plesk panel via akeeba backup . Where I,m facing file permission issue.

```
An error occured

Could not open /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/pearl_new/jquery.min.js for writing.
```

As searched all over and also in Plesk forum . I found this is a very common problem. Some suggested installing mod_suphp can solve the problem. I tried but don't know is it successfully installed or not.

Then I have created a new service plan from where in hosting parameter I select `Run PHP as FastCGI`

After that I took my domain to that service plan. I thought it will solve the problem. But still getting same error. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Can you tell owner:group and permissions on this file? If you don't have shell access, you can see them in File Manager.

Answer (score 1):

On the ssh command line try:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

these will set the permissions correct for writing to by user and group for files (f) and directories (d).  you also need to make sure that apache is in the psacln and psaserv groups in the /etc/group file: the lines should look like this:

```
psaserv:x:504:apache,psaftp,psaadm
psacln:x:505:apache
```

Then you can run the commad:

```
chown -R siteusername.psacln /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/*
```

where "siteusername" is the username of the site's files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this ownership structure expects php open_basedir to be active, in order to secure co-hosted websites? Is there also a suitable config which makes use of chmods to protect files?

Answer (score 1):

this is common issue in linux and users had shared hosting.

So simple.
If you already selected PHP module with FAST CGi so follow the following steps:
Open file manager 
Make new folder "ABC"
Click "ALL" on right side to view all files on the tree.
Select all files and folders except "plesk-stats"
Select Copy/move button
in the path filed type /httpdocs/abc/
Click Move.

If all files moved and then open "abc" folder
Select all files and folders. 
Select Copy/move button
in the path filed type /httpdocs/

that's it issue sorted out.

I tried these steps for many clients.

I hope this helps for someone.